# Handlebars template accessing parent object from deep level

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

My doubt is currently I am accessing parent node from deep node like below code. Is it correct approach?

JSON:

```
myObj = {

    level1_1 : [

        {
            level2 : [

                {level3 : 'String'}
            ]
        }

    ],

    level1_2 : 'String'

}
```

Template:

```
{{#each level1_1}}
    {{#each level2}}
        {{level3}}

        {{!-- Here I want to access level1_2 -- }}

        {{../../level1_2}} {{!-- Is is correct approach ??-- }}

        {{!-- If it is even deep level -- }} {{../../../../level1_2}} {{!--like this--}} {{!-- Is is correct approach ??-- }}

    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an upcoming feature of the new handlebars version.

I created a fiddle with the 2.0 alpha 4 version of Handlebars for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jbrosi/zZE3k/

@root will give you access to the context-root. In your example you can access level1_2 from anywhere by using:

```
{{@root.level1_2}}
```

There's also a patched version of the 1.3 out there somewhere where you can get support for @root (I'm using it myself) but I can't remember where I got it :(. I'll update this answer if I can find the link for the patched 1.3.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can use @root only to acces top parent right? 
Is there any thing to access 2/3 steps back?

Comment: You're welcome, and you are right, the @root is only for the top parent. For other levels the ../../ etc. syntax is the way to go.